# Using PHP to trim/correctly display the Time MySQL datatype

Tags: php, mysql, time

First question here, so please forgive me if this seems obvious. I'm having a bit of an issue working with the 'TIME' datatype in my MySQL database and trying to find the best way to trim the leading zeros off the beginning of the time stamp.

To be more specific, I have a songs table in my database, and in that table I have a song_length column. This column uses the Time datatype, so the presentation is always hh:mm:ss.

If my song is only 3 minutes and 42 seconds (for example), I'm hoping to have it display as simply: 3:42, as opposed to 00:03:42. Is there a built in PHP function (perhaps similar to date()) to deal with something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it into an array, then cast each part as an int

```
$time = '00:03:42';
$parts = explode(':', $time);
$hours = (int) $parts[0];
$minutes = (int) $parts[1];
$seconds = (int) $parts[2];
```

If I were you though, I'd store the time as an integer representing the number of seconds.

Comment: Thank you for this! Besides the obvious (being able to easily do the math to determine the minutes/hours), are there any other significant benefits to storing the time as an Int datatype as opposed to the Time datatype?

Comment: If you wanted to sort by the time column it *may* be easier (I don't know whether MySQL can sort a TIME col). Also, if you wanted to - say - get the average length of songs by a particular artist.

Answer (score 1):

There is `date()` You just need to make sure you use a different format when `$hours > 0`

```
$d = new DateTime($time);
echo $d->format('H') > 0
   ? ltrim($d->format('H:i:s'), '0') 
   : ltrim($d->format('i:s'),   '0');
```

http://ideone.com/eAWun

Comment: Thank you for the rapid help, King. This was exactly what I was looking for (if I decide to continue to keep the time as a Time datatype as opposed to an Int). Thanks again!

Comment: +1 as, in the context of TIME fields, it's probably a better solution!